# getting 401 error when opening the url of my service after deployed in aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, migration, cloud

I have created a sample demo which is having one get method and returns a string.
Deployed successfully in AWS cloud and while running the url it is showing as

```
[{"Code":"401 Unauthorized","Description":"Authentication: ID Token is required.","Source":"xxxxx"}]
```

In my local I can able to load swagger and get response but not in AWS cloud url.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Authentication mode:

1. through role
2. through key (USer)

then Check the permission assigned to that particular role or user